# gradle does not work correctly

Tags: android, gradle

I was working with Android Studio and i decided to add recyclerView to build.gradle. but after added it and syncing gradle i got this error:

[image]

```
    Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies]
```

even i do **Rebuild project** but in this task also i got same error. for other way i did **invalidate caches/Restart** but it did not work an still my problem exist.
I turn off **instant run** but i got same error.
I deleted .gradle folder in my user and still i got this error!!!
how can i pass this problem?

my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.sayres.mychat"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner  "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),  'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-  core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile('org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.0.2') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
compile('org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.0.3-SNAPSHOT') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Edit:

in the gradle console apeare these lines:

```
Error: Some file crunching failed, see logs for details
```

:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

  > Error: Some file crunching failed, see logs for details
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or     --debug option to get more log output.

  BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.358 secs

and this is my log: [enter link description here](http://codepad.org/Zoh8SAn8)

I delete **build** folder but i got same error. in these folders there is no PNG images.

Comment: Add you gradle in question.

Comment: The line you have posted is not an error.

Comment: @Henry i add an image

Comment: And what did you find in the logs?

Comment: try by cleaning the project

Comment: @Nikhya I did everything but i think it was windows problem. because in finally i've done fresh install windows and this problem had been disappeared

Answer (score 1):

Try this in gradle, Make sure you clean your project:

```
 android {
 aaptOptions {  
            cruncherEnabled = false  
        } 
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: don't copy the android tag just copy aaptOptions and paste it in android tag.

Comment: I know, and i just copy aaptOptions.